# Return an object but with one property different

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

In the following code I want to return all the same keys and values except the property color. If the name is default, return the `color: '#1F2532'`, if it's different than default, it will call a function that gives me random colors `color: pickColor([])`. But I think there is a better way to write this instead of repeating code and just changing the property color. How can I do this?

```
class Project {

  static createProject(data) {
    if (data.name !== 'default') {
      return {
        owner: {
          name: data.owner,
          avatar: data.ownerAvatar
        },
        users: [
          {
            name: data.owner,
            avatar: data.ownerAvatar,
            active: true,
          }],
        name: data.name,
        retrospectives: [],
        color: pickColor([])
      }
    } else {
      return {
        owner: {
          name: data.owner,
          avatar: data.ownerAvatar
        },
        users: [
          {
            name: data.owner,
            avatar: data.ownerAvatar,
            active: true,
          }],
        name: data.name,
        retrospectives: [],
        color: '#1F2532'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in a comment above, using a conditional assignment would be your best bet:

```
class Project {

  static createProject(data) {
    return {
      owner: {
        name: data.owner,
        avatar: data.ownerAvatar
      },
      users: [
        {
          name: data.owner,
          avatar: data.ownerAvatar,
          active: true,
        }],
      name: data.name,
      retrospectives: [],
      color: data.name === 'default' ? '#1F2532' : pickColor([])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with javascript, so please excuse me if I get some semantics wrong. The simple answer is to change the position of "`if`".

```
class Project {
  static createProject(data) {
      return {
        owner: {
          name: data.owner,
          avatar: data.ownerAvatar
        },
        users: [
          {
            name: data.owner,
            avatar: data.ownerAvatar,
            active: true,
          }],
        name: data.name,
        retrospectives: [],
        if (data.name !== 'default') {
            color: pickColor([])
        } else {
        color: '#1F2532'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An alternative to

```
    if (data.name !== 'default') {
        color: pickColor([])
    } else {
    color: '#1F2532'
  }
```

is

```
colour: (data.name == 'default' ? '#1F2532' : pickColor([]))
```

p.s. haven't counted the brackets either, but you get the drift.

Comment: You can't put an if-statement into an object literal. A conditional expression however should work fine.